# AutoMapper , WCF and multi layers : how to do with dependency

Tags: c#, wcf, automapper

I have a WCF project with multiple layers ( and DTO object ) :

-Service ( WCF Host )
   -Business Layer ( or Domain Layer )
   -Data Access Layer ( using Entity framework )

To retrieve database informations , i want to use automapper to map Entity object To DTO object .

But if i configure mapping in global.asax , my problem is : the Service layer does not reference Data Access layer (and i dont want this).

How can i do ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what are you going to map, DAC (Entity) to Service Model or DAC to UI (ViewModel) ?

Comment: Hi , dac to service model. But i have business layer between service and data

Comment: But your data layer must return a model object, a entity object. If this model is separate from dac, you can reference to the model in your service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're using AutoMapper 5.1, which includes profile scanning. First, you'd want to put your configuration into profiles at the appropriate places:

```
public class EntityToDtoProfile : Profile {
    public EntityToDtoProfile() {
         CreateMap<Entity, Dto>();
    }
}
```

Next, in your WCF app, wherever the app startup is, you'll initialize AutoMapper, passing in the assembly names to scan for profiles:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfiles(new [] {
        "MyLayeredApp.BLL",
        "MyLayeredApp.DAL",
        "MyLayeredApp.Service"
    });
});
```

AutoMapper will scan those assemblies for Profiles, and register them in the configuration. Make sure you only call Mapper.Initialize once at startup, like you would any other app-wide configuration.

Or, just create one WCF project, collapse all those projects into one, and use folders for organization instead of all this. That also works.